# Unmet Dependecies

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I am facing the issue of unmet dependencies.

If you are using third party repositories then disable them, since they are a common source of problems.

Now run the following command in a terminal: `apt-get install -f`

The transaction failed: The package system is broken

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libcairo2:i386: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
                Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12) but 2.12.6-0ubuntu2 is installed
                Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.7.1) but 2.8.1-2ubuntu2 is installed
                Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2 is installed
libfreetype6: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
              Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2 is installed
libfreetype6:i386: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
                   Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2 is installed
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried apt-get install -f, apt-get --fix-broken install. The issue is still persistent.

Comment: You seemed to be installling a package meant for an old version of Ubuntu, probably 10.04. What is the package you are installing? Post the exact .deb file and source, or if installing from apt repository, your content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: Thank you for reply. I was trying to install questasim and was following the instructions in an online article. I did the following steps:

Comment: wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb

Comment: wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb

Comment: sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb

Comment: sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb

Comment: sudo dpkg -i libfreetype6_2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb

Comment: Does questasim have a `.deb` package? If so, install the package and it will tell you the missing packages. To install `libpng` or other packages in Ubuntu, avoid directly downloading them. Instead, use this command: `sudo apt install -y libpng-dev`. 


In addition, this article seems sensible on steps to install Questasim http://www.anthonyvh.com/2017/10/13/questasim_on_ubuntu/ . I am guessing the Overlay bug has been fixed and you don't need to perform the NFS mount steps.

Comment: There was a warning when I ran this that libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_i386 will be reverted to libfreetype6_2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386. I am new to ubuntu and tried to resolve looking at some online help. Nothing worked.

Comment: Questasim doesn't have .deb package. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: as I mentioned in the earlier comment, use `sudo apt install <package>`, e.g. `sudo apt install libfreetype6`

Comment: libfreetype6 is already the newest version (2.8.1-2ubuntu2).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. After running this command i got the following

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6/FTL.TXT.gz', which is different from other instances of package libfreetype6:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Please don't put all that information in comments, you can edit your own questions so it can be added there. Question text allows greater formatting, and primarily is far easier to read.